# The sharpness of discrete Hilbert transform.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $a=(a_n)\in \ell^p$ for $p>1$. It is known that $H(a)=\sum_{n\neq m, n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{a_n}{m-n}$ is a bounded linear operator from $\ell^p$  to $\ell^p$. I'm trying to see if this result can be extended to $\mathbb{Z}^d$ for $d>1$. But it looks like it cannot be extended to any higher-dimensional space. My reasoning is the following.

Consider just the case $d=2$ and suppose to the contrary that $$H(a)=\sum_{n_1+n_2\neq m_1+m_2,\, (n_1,n_2)\in \mathbb{Z^2}}\frac{a_{n_1,n_2}}{(m_1-n_1)+(m_2-n_2)}$$
is a bounded linear operator from $\ell^p$ to $\ell^p$, i.e, $$\|{H(a)}\|_{\ell^p}\leq C_p \|a\|_{\ell^p}.$$

Since the permutation of $a$ is still in $\ell^p$, the following infinite sum
$$\sum_{n_1+n_2\neq m_1+m_2,\, (n_1,n_2)\in \mathbb{Z^2}}\frac{a_{n_1,n_2}}{(m_1-n_1)+(m_2-n_2)} -(*)$$
has to be unconditionally convergent.
So, we can rearrange $(*)$ and get
$$\sum_{n_1+n_2\neq m_1+m_2} \sum_{n_1+n_2 = k, k\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{a_{n_1,n_2}}{m_1+m_2-k} $$

Now consider $a_{n_1,n_2}=\frac{1}{|n_1|}+\frac{1}{|n_2|}$ and equals $0$ when one of $n_1,n_2$ is $0$. Then $(a_{n_1,n_2})$ is in $\ell^p$ for any $p>1.$ We can see that $$\sum_{n_1+n_2 = k, k\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{a_{n_1,n_2}}{m_1+m_2-k}\geq \frac{1}{m_1+m_2-k}\sum_{n_1\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{|n_1|}=\infty$$, which is a contradiction. This establishes that the boundedness of discrete Hilbert transform cannot be extended to $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$, and similarly, any $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ for $d>2$. Not 100% sure if I did something wrong, any comment or reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The denominator vanishes for $n_1+n_2=m_1+m_2.$ Perhaps you should redefine the operator.

Comment: The operator is unbounded as the function $(m_1+m_2)^{-1}$ for $m_1+m_2\neq 0$  does not belong to $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ for any $p<\infty.$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think I meant to say $m_1+m_2\neq n_1+n_2$.

Comment: The sequence $|n_1|^{-1}+|n_2|^{-1}$ does not belong to $\ell^p$ for any $p<\infty$ as $$\sum_{n_1=1}\sum_{n_2=1}(n_1^{-1}+n_2^{-1})^p=\infty$$ For example if $p=m$ then by the binomial theorem we get $(n_1^{-1}+n_2^{-1})^m\ge mn_1^{-1}n_2^{-(m-1)}$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You are right, I have to think about another counterexample.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks.